# Postfix - Set the reply-to address based on the sent-to address when sending email

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I have multiple domains which I receive e-mail for and have set up my mailserver to deliver it all to a single mailbox for convenience, example below:

```
comment@myblog.com
contact@mybusiness.com
admin@mywebsite.com
```

They all come to me at my single mailbox:

```
ian@me.com
```

When I reply to these e-mails the reply-to address will be:

```
ian@me.com
```

I would like to automatically have postfix change that reply-to address, based on the address that the e-mail was originally sent to, so for example:

```
Email is sent to me at: comment@myblog.com
I reply from: ian@me.com
I want the reply-to to be: comment@myblog.com
```

Is there a way to automate this with postfix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It is doable in postfix anyway. But it requires some programming to parse the mail to determine the recipient email address and add `Reply-To` header from that value. You need to use an external [content filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html) or a [Milter application](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html). But I dont think it is a cleaner way.
- I would rather say that setting `Reply-To` header should be done by the `MUA` eg. (Thunderbird, Outlook etc ) instead of `Postfix MTA`. For eg. in `Thunderbird`, If you receive all your emails for

  ```
  comment@myblog.com
  contact@mybusiness.com
  admin@mywebsite.com
  ```

  at `ian@me.com`, then you can add identities for all the email addresses above( You can set your Name, Email address, Reply-To address etc). So when you reply to an email sent to `comment@myblog.com`, then the `Reply-To` address will be set to `comment@myblog.com`.  For `Thunderbird`, you have to add identities by clicking `Edit -> Account Settings -> Manage Identities`. More info [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/configuring-email-aliases#w_using-identities-to-specify-a-reply-to-address). All `MUA`s should have this option of managing identities.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi clement, thanks for the response. This may be easier than the programmatically getting postfix to do it. I am somewhat worried about needing to maintain that across different devices. However I will leave the question open for a bit and if no other replies come I will mark yours as the answer. :)